# Is This Interpretation of Auxiliary Independent Vector Analysis (AuxIVA) Correct?

Tags: source-separation, ica

I am implementing auxiliary function based Independent Vector Analysis (AuxIVA) from  Nobutaka Ono's original paper [Stable and fast update rules for independent vector analysis based on auxiliary function technique](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6082320/). AuxIVA is also presented in other freely available papers, for example [this one](https://asap.ite.tul.cz/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2016/07/SparseAuxIVAv3.pdf). It is an extension of plain Independent Vector Analysis where an auxiliary function of the original cost function is minimized.

There are four equations that make up the update rules of AuxIVA:

$$ r_k = \sqrt{\sum_{\omega=1}^{N_\omega} {\lvert w_k^h(\omega)x(\omega)\rvert}^2} $$
$$ V_k(\omega) = {1\over{N_t}}\sum_{t=1}^{N_t}{{G'(r_k) \over r_k} x(\omega) x^h(\omega) } $$
$$ w_k(\omega) = (W(\omega)V_k(\omega))^{-1}e_k$$
$$ w_k(\omega) = {w_k(\omega) \over {\sqrt {w_k^h(\omega)V_k(\omega)w_k(\omega)}}} $$

where

$ N_s $ is the number of sources.

$ k = 1,2,...,N_s$ is the source index.

$ e_k = [0,0,...0,1,0...]^T $, is a column vector with its only non-zero entry being a 1 at the k-th index.

$ G'(r_k)$ is the first derivative of the AuxIVA contrast function and since I'm using $G(r) = r$, $ G'(r_k) = 1$.

$ N_w $ is the number of frequency bins and $ N_t $ is the number of time bins in the STFT of the mixture.

The input I am using is structured like this:

1. $X$ is a tensor $N_s  * N_t * N_\omega $ which is the short-time Fourier transform (STFT) of $N_s$ mixtures.
2. $W$ is the mixing tensor that will be estimated by repeatedly applying the 4 update rules. Its dimensions are $N_s*N_s*N_\omega$

In Matlab notation, $w^h_k(\omega) = W[k,:,\omega] $ and $x(\omega)=X[:,:,\omega]$.

When I evaluate $r_k$ using the first equation , I get a vector of size $ 1 * N_t $.

To evaluate $V_k(\omega)$ using the second equation, I evaluate $ {G'(r_k) \over r_k}$, which is just $r_k$ because of the assumption $G(r_k) = r_k$. I then do point-wise multiplication between $ {G'(r_k) \over r_k} $ and $x(\omega)$ then post-multiply this product by $x^h(\omega)$. Because $x(\omega)$ has size $N_s*N_t$ and $ {G'(r_k) \over r_k} $, the point-wise multiplication between them a weighted copy of $x(\omega)$. When this weighted copy is post-multiplied by $x^h(\omega)$, a weighted covariance matrix of size $N_s*N_s$ is generated.

In the third equation I post-multiply $W(\omega)$, that has size $N_s*N_s$, by $V_k(\omega)$ from the previous equation, that has size $N_s*N_s$. I then invert this matrix to get $(W(\omega)V_k(\omega))^{-1}$ and post-multiply this by $e_k$ to get $w_k(\omega)$ that is a vector of size $1*N_s$

Finally, in the last equation, I evaluate ${\sqrt {w_k^h(\omega)V_k(\omega)w_k}}$, that is a scalar, and divide the vector $w_k(\omega)$ by this scalar to get a scaled version of $w_k(\omega)$.

I'd like to know if my interpretation of the four equations is correct. I do not have an in-depth understanding of the derivation of these equations so I'm relying on little information present in these papers to interpret and implement the algorithm.

Comment: Are you sure about " G′(rk) which is the first derivative of the AuxIVA contrast function using G(r)=rG(r)=r, G′(rk)=1G′(rk)=1. " ? Even I have the same doubt. Please let me know if you know the answer by now.
Your understanding on the other 3 equations are right according to my understanding.

Comment: @Gautam : PLEASE DO NOT POST COMMENTS AS ANSWERS. Earn enough rep to allow posting of comments, first.

Comment: @Gautam I couldn't quite get good results from AuxIVA, most likely the result of a logical or programming bug. G'(r_k) is definitely 1. For example in the paper "Auxiliary Function Independent Vector Analysis Using a Harmonic Clique Dependence Model" look at equation 29, which is a variation of the AuxIVA term G'(r_k)/r_k and notice the numerators and denominators.

Answer (score 1):

I think your understanding is right, and it has already been implemented in many open sourced codes, like https://github.com/LCAV/pyroomacoustics and https://github.com/n-narisawa/bss

However, the performance of AUXIVA is not as good as original IVA according to my experiements. Do you have some new conclusions about the performance and the real-time implementation of AUXIVA? Thanks.

Comment: First a huge thanks for replying. I finally have an answer after over 2 years. I moved away from the project some 2 years ago so I have forgotten most of the analysis but my Matlab implementation never worked. The output did not get separated cleanly in the more than 100 experiments I ran with data collected from the field as well as synthetic mixtures. If I remember correctly, all the algorithm did was to add some distortion in the output. There was likely a flaw in my implementation but with the replication crisis we are seeing in science I won't rule out false claims either.